# What are the advantages of discards in c#

Tags: c#

I've just come across discards in c# and am wondering a couple things that I feel [Microsoft Docs on Discards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) didn't explain very well.

1. With a standalone discard is it just meant for readability?  If I had a function that returned a result (that isn't necessarily needed), let's say a `bool` or `int`, but also did some other logic then why use a discard when you can simply call the function outside of an assignment?

For example:

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
NetworkStream nc = tcpClient.GetStream();
// what's the difference between
nc.Read(someBuffer, 0, someSize);
// and the discard
_ = nc.Read(someBuffer, 0, someSize);
```

Don't they both just discard the result anyways?  This looks like it is purely a preference thing to me.

2. In Microsoft's documentation about discards it is eluded that it'll reduce memory allocations is this because they are equivalent to unassigned variables?
3. What are the performance benefits of discards if there are any and it is it just a stylistic thing meant to improve readability?

**Edit:**

To be more clear: I'm just curious if there are any potential performance benefits to using discards.  The Microsoft doc link that I provided states "there is only a single discard variable, and that variable may not even be allocated storage, discards can reduce memory allocations", in which use case (pattern matching, calls to methods with out, tuple deconstruction and/or standalone) are memory allocations reduced?

Comment: Isn't most of this covered in the first paragraph of the docs you've linked? `Because there is only a single discard variable, and that variable may not even be allocated storage, discards can reduce memory allocations. Because they make the intent of your code clear, they enhance its readability and maintainability.`. And other benefits to specific scenarios within each section of that doc.

Comment: Yes but it says 'may not even be allocated', hence my confusion.  And, yes it does give examples and reasons to use it as far as ignoring it.  What I'm really interested in is performance benefits.  Does it or doesn't it allocate memory for the discarded object.  If the discarded objects are allocated in memory when is it released?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In general, there is no sense to use discard in this sentence:

```
_ = nc.Read(someBuffer, 0, someSize);
```

since you can just ignore the return value. I did never anyone using standalone discards, but the documentation covers some specific cases when it can be useful.

The discards are used when you **have to** provide a variable, but don't need it.
  As already covered in the provided documentation page, discards are very useful for:

### Pattern matching

```
switch (stream)
{
    case MemoryStream _:
    case FileStream _:
        ProcessStream(stream);
        break;
}
```

### Methods with out parameters

If you want to check if you can parse a string to an integer, but don't care about the result:

```
if (int.TryParse(str, out _))
{
    // do something
}
```

Otherwise, you would have to declare an out variable, which you wouldn't use and which  would consume some memory.

### Deconstruction

```
(_, _, area) = city.GetCityInformation(cityName);
```

Without discards you would deconstruct the result into 3 different variables, and use only one of them. With discards the code has cleaner intentions and more ineffective in terms of memory management.

Comment: Just to add to @yeldar's comment, I have used discards in class deconstruction quite a bit already.  That is the only place where I have found where they are of a good use.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this deals more with initial memory allocation rather than JUST memory management. So if you do not consume the output variable then it is still going to pushed onto the stack regardless if it is a ref type. (Yeah so the val types in your question won't be and I see your point there.) but if you are dealing with something like a filestream and didn't close the stream then I believe you are going to be holding onto that for the application lifecycle. That said then you have to be conscious of anything implementing IDisposable. I would think that discards could have a relatively bigger impact in that regard.

Past that, dealing with out params passed into functions, it prevents the initial memory allocation of those variables since you won't be using them. It may not have a huge impact on smaller projects but if you have some method that is used excessively across an application then it's use is more applicable than just some new trendy style.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but do you believe and think or do you know? Please provide some references. It's a serious question and is not covered in most of the articles and tutorials. Should I start using discard and assign my expressions to it? Is there any advantage in term of performance?

Answer (score 0):

Discards are equivalent to unassigned variables; they do not have a value. Because there is only a single discard variable, and that variable may not even be allocated storage, discards can reduce memory allocations. Because they make the intent of your code clear, they enhance its readability and maintainability. **They are basically a way to ignore local variables those are irrelevant to perform the action, it is like when you call a method that returns a value, however, you are interested only in the underlying operations it performs**, you don't use the return of that method.

As we can see on the example below, discards are particularly useful in working with tuples when your application code uses some tuple elements but ignores others:

> Note: I have got the example from Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards) and I have included a second output just to show the difference

```
public class Example
{
   public static void Main()
   {
       var (_, _, _, pop1, _, pop2) = QueryCityDataForYears("New York City", 1960, 2010);
       var (cityName, _, year1, pop3, _, pop4) = QueryCityDataForYears("New York City", 1980, 2010);

       Console.WriteLine($"Population change, in 1960 to 2010: {pop2 - pop1:N0}");
       Console.WriteLine($"Population change, in {cityName}  from {year1} to 2010: {pop4 - pop3:N0}");
   }

    private static (string, double, int, int, int, int) QueryCityDataForYears(string name, int year1, int year2)
    {
        int population1 = 0, population2 = 0;
        double area = 0;

        if (name == "New York City") 
        {
            area = 468.48; 
            if (year1 == 1960) 
            {
                population1 = 7781984;
            }
            if (year1 == 1980) 
            {
                population1 = 7981984;
            }
            if (year2 == 2010) 
            {
                population2 = 8175133;
            }

            return (name, area, year1, population1, year2, population2);
        }

        return ("", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
}

//Output
//Population change, in 1960 to 2010: 393,149
//Population change, in New York City  from 1980 to 2010: 193,149
```