# Using discards in C# for return methods

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

Does the use of discards in C# have any performance benefit? In Visual Studio 2019, the editor suggests using discards for return type methods that are not using the returned value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the advantages of discards in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55693693/what-are-the-advantages-of-discards-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is little benefit in using discards. It's the same as an unassigned variable, so less memory usage is a benefit. How much of a benefit is unknown. Visual Studio also keeps on suggesting that I use discards, but I just surpressed that message from the popup.

Comment: I prefer to use the discards. It makes the intent of the code clearer.

Answer (score 4):

Accroding to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards)

> Discards which are temporary, dummy variables that are intentionally
>   unused in application code. Discards are equivalent to unassigned
>   variables; they do not have a value. Because there is only a single
>   discard variable, and that variable may not even be allocated storage,
>   discards can reduce memory allocations.

As you can see, you can reduce a memory usage, because they may not be allocated. But exact behavior depends on context of your code.

The main use cases of discards are tuples, pattern matching in `switch` expression

```cs
switch (obj)
{
     case SomeType someTypeValue:
        ...
        break;
     case null:
        ...
        break;
     case object _:
        ...
        break;
}
```

methods with `out` parameters

```cs
if (int.TryParse(s, out _))
{    
}
```

and just ignore a return value from a method `_ = Task.Run(() => {...});`, like you want.

There is also a big usability benefit in terms of clean code. By using a discard `_` you've indicating the return value is unused one

Comment: Yeah but its very very ugly when stringbuilder append returns back a stringbuilder so you get `_ = sb.AppendLine("something");` all over the place. Its nice and useful when you use them in `out` params, but the options to choose where they are used are very very limited

Answer (score 0):

Well. It depends.

(1) Without discards, you need something like:

```
            string foo = "fish";
            bool parsingok2 = Double.TryParse(foo, out double res);
```

(2) With discards it is a little easier to write:

```
            string foo = "fish";
            bool parsingok1 = Double.TryParse(foo, out _);
```

So. If the compiler is smart and notices that the res in (1) is never used, it could build code like (2) automatically. And as far as I know, the compiler is quite smart.

In that example, looking at the disassembled code both look equal to me, so really no difference at all.